# Reconnect WebRTC in IOS (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, reconnect

I have a problem. After I connected 2 clients by webRTC (IOS). When one client changes wifi another client receive state "RTCIceConnectionStateDisconnected" but it doesn't reconnect! Please help me.

I wanna it reconnected when changing another wifi.

Thank you so much.

Comment: it won't reconnect automatically. The address has been changed, the other client doesn't know the new location of the device which has changed the network.

Comment: You have to establish a new connection from.

Comment: You may want to take a look on [this][1] option.


  [1]: https://quickblox.com/developers/IOS